# get object and line intersection?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, intersection

Does anyone know how to acquire intersection point(x,y,z) of line and an object in opengl es 2.0. I need basic algorithms or links. i was searching for this answer for 2 days and i couldn`t figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For faster rendering on embedded devices avoid using all of the object's vertices.

Ultimately you have to use tricks:

1) When detecting collision, develop as per your convenience methods to approximate object

2) Use single point to represent object, and check if

```
foreach(LINEPOINTS)
  if (MVP * LINEPOINTS).x or .y or .z equals (MVP * objectCentre).x or .y or .z
```

3) Use seperate way, (anyother language that you know like I use Perl) for finding centre,
as simple as

```
count = numofvertices
foreach vertices
    sumx += x;
    sumy += y;
    sumz += z;
centreofmass = {sumx/count, sumy/count, sumz/count}
```

use this value directly as private float[] final objectCentre = centreofmass

4) When this works, use more vertices (like edgecentres or corners of shapes), that too precalculated in someotherlanguage and then used in java app as mentioned before, because object will have huge number of vertices and approximating does not mean it does not look nice, it will look nice but spend more time to find ways that suit you app

Comment: thanks. i was not clear in the question. my problem is when i touch on the screen A RAY parallel to the view line fires and it intersect with some point on the object`s surface. So I read your answer
1) when detecting collision
how do you detect the collision between ray and surface